# Simple select from table takes 24 seconds in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, performance, indexing, query-optimization, sql-server-2014

I have a table named [cwbOrder] that currently has 1.277.469 rows. I am using SQL Server 2014 and I am doing these tests on a UAT environment, on production this query takes a little bit longer.

If I try selecting all of the rows like using:

`SELECT * FROM cwbOrder`

It takes 24 seconds to retrieve all of the data from the table. I have read about how it is important to index columns used in the predicates (WHERE), but I still cannot understand how does a simple select take 24 seconds.

[image]

Using this table in other more complex queries generates a lot of extra workload for the query, although I have created the JOINs on indexed columns. Additionally I have selected only 2 columns from this table then JOINED it to another table and this operation still takes a significantly long amount of time. As an example please consider the below query:

[image]

Below I have attached the index structure of both tables, to illustrate the matter:

[image]

PK_cwbOrder is the index on the id_cwbOrder column in the cwbOrder table.

[image]

Edit 1: I have added the execution plan for the query in which I join the cwbOrder table with the cwbAction table.

[image]

Is there any way, considering the information above, that I can make this query faster?

Comment: What is the row count in the action table. How many order ids exist in it that are in the order table. What is the relationship between the two tables. If the selectivity is not that low, the optimiser would just do full scans.

Comment: @AbBennett - check the post again, I have added the execution plan for the second query. Also tried suggestions to select a limited number of rows (10 rows) and counting the rows of the table cwbOrder, but did not get any conclusive information.

Comment: _Displaying_ those 1277469 rows will already take up a substantial amount of time.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is this standard behavior? I tested on another UAT environment and got to the same conclusion (different client, different system), still took around 9 seconds to display 500k rows.

Comment: That depends on the SQL _client_ you are using (looks like SSMS). But displaying a result with a million rows will never be fast. Try to open an Excel Sheet with a million rows. Or a text file with a million lines. Or a HTML table in your browser with a million rows

Comment: >>>Below I have attached the index structure of both tables<<< You did NOT attach any table structure. It's still unknown how wide is your table and if it contains LOB data. There is a great difference between 2 tables both containing 1 mln of row but the first has only 1 int column and the second XML column with 1 Gb XML entries

Comment: to @a_horse_with_no_name's point, try doing `SELECT * INTO #TEST_TEMP_TABLE FROM cwbOrder` to test how long its really taking to read the records, as opposed to display the records to the end user in SSMS. Also, I'd ask how many columns do you have in this table? And what are the data types? If you have `datetime` content in `varchar(50)` columns it can make a difference on run time. Can you run `exec sp_spaceused 'db.sch.cwbOrder'` (
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-spaceused-transact-sql) and show the results?

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why such a `select` could be slow:

- The row size or number of rows could be very large, requiring a lot of time to transport or delay.
- Other operations on the table could have locks on the table.
- The database server or network could be very busy.
- The "table" could really be a view that is running a complicated query.

You can test different aspects.  For instance:

```
SELECT TOP 10 <one column here>
FROM cwbOrder o
```

This returns a very small result set and reads just a small part of the table.  This reads the entire table but returns a small result set:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM cwbOrder o
```

Comment: I have tested both aspects and `SELECT TOP 10 <one column here>
FROM cwbOrder o`, (I have used order_externalId) runs in 0 seconds, so does `SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM cwbOrder o`, returning 1 row with the total number of records 1.277.469. Is there any way that I can make this query run faster (The simple select)?

Comment: @RaduN. . . . This would suggest either activity o the server or possibly that `cwbOrder` has some very large columns.  If the latter, try selecting only one or two columns instead of `select *`.

Comment: I tried `SELECT <column 1>, <column 2> FROM cwbOrder` and it returned 1.277.469 in 8 seconds. Are there any specific indicators that I should monitor for activity on the server? Do you know/suggest* any specific KPIs that I can monitor for impact on the query activity?

Comment: @RaduN. . . . Your problem would appear to be the network between you and the server.  You might want to save the data in a table or file.  Do you really need all 1.2 million rows in your application?

Comment: I was running the aforementioned query directly on the dedicated DB Server, on the application server there is a slightly bigger run time. I did this check specifically to prevent this type of "problems" to interfere with the run time.